# Convert Dataset element to string array in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to convert the dataset item into the string and save into    the array. But it gives me syntax error. Please help me out. This in VS 2005 and C#

Thanks in advance!!

```
string strdetailID[] = new string[4];
for(int i = 0; i < x ; i++)
{
   strdetailID[i] = dsImages.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Ad_detailsID"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this isn't all the code and you are declaring i?

Comment: What's the text of the error?

Comment: its not the complete code. I thought its not necessary, sorry. I give you little more code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<string> strDetailIDList = new List<string>();    

foreach(DataRow row in dsImages.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    strDetailIDList.Add(row["Ad_detailsID"].ToString());
}

string strDetailID[] = strDetailIDList.ToArray();
```

I have used a `List<string>` instead of a `string` array, as I think it would be easier to dynamically add elements, but if you want to still use a `string` array, you should get the general idea.

Comment: I understand using of List<string> would be easy, but i was wondering what if i use string array? Is there no way you can save a dataset item into array? I am curious, dont take me wrong!

Comment: @Ram a string array is a set amount of items to it, so you can't just add elements to the array dynamically.  I have added code into my post to set a string array to the List<string> elements.  The end product is the string array with you necessary values.

Comment: I got you.. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] strdetailID = new string[4];
for(int i = 0; i < x ; i++)
{
   strdetailID[i] = dsImages.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Ad_detailsID"].ToString();
}
```

This will work ..you made a mistake string strdetailID[]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to size array before for each loop and form array directly without list.

```
string [] strDetailID = new string[dsImages.Tables[0].Rows.Count];   
int arryIndex = 0;
foreach(DataRow row in dsImages.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    strDetailID [arryIndex] = row["Ad_detailsID"].ToString());
    arryIndex++;

}
```